# Google Custom Search API PHP curl Post XML HTTP 411 error

Tags: php, xml, post, google-custom-search

I have tried several different methods of sending a POST request with my xml to add an annotation to my google custom search.  Each different method that I've tried has resulted in a HTTP 411 error (POST requests require a Content-length header).  Here is my current code:

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=****&Passwd=*****&service=cprose&source=ednovo-classadmin-1';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $authTokenData = curl_exec($ch);
    $authTokenArray = explode('Auth=', $authTokenData);
    $authToken = $authTokenArray[1];

    echo "got token: $authToken<br>";

    $annotation = $_POST['annotation'];
    $label = $_POST['label'];
    $href = $_POST['href'];
    curl_close($ch);
    $data ='<Batch>' .
                '<Add>' .
                    '<Annotations>' .
                        '<Annotation about = "' . $annotation . '">' .
                            '<Label name = "' . $label . '" />' .
                        '</Annotation>' .
                    '</Annotations>' .
                '</Add>' .
            '</Batch>';
   $url = "http://www.google.com/cse/api/default/annotations/";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $length = strlen($data);
    $header = array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $authToken, "Content-Type: text/xml","Content-Length: " . $length);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 200:
            break;
        default:
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode;
            break;
    }
}

    echo $result;
?>
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Thank you.

---

I appreciate your help as this was one of my problems.  However, it is still giving me the same HTTP 411 error even after using the init and changing the header.  Do you have any other ideas?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You don't need to set the Content-Length header cURL does this auto

Answer (score 1):

You called `curl_close($ch);` after the first request for ClientLogin, but you forgot to do a `$ch = curl_init();` again for the second request. Add you don't need to put the Content-Length header field; curl populates this automatuically when setting the post fields/data. You could also try adding quotes on the auth value in the Authorization field.

```
$header = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="'. $authToken.'"', "Content-Type: text/xml");
```

And always remove your Google Apps login credentials when posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be [0] ?   Maybe not,  just a suggestion.

```
 $authToken = $authTokenArray[1];
```

Still working on figuring it out for you ....

Comment: It's correct, here is the docs on the response of ClientLogin http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html#Response